# I keep getting Redirect Loop error in Rails Application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, backend

I'm running a Rails application and testing the endpoints via Postman, when I log in and try to access the endpoints they work normally as always, but as I wait some time while logged in and try to access the endpoint again I get this Redirect Error:

[Postman Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XWvuK.png)

And in the terminal I get 401 Unauthorized, as if it had logged out, but it keeps trying the endpoint instead of just returning the 401 and stopping:

```
    Started GET "/api/employees/getAgenda?month=7&year=2021" for 127.0.0.1 at 2021-07-15 17:39:32 -0300
Processing by Api::EmployeesController#getAgenda as */*
  Parameters: {"month"=>"7", "year"=>"2021"}
MONGODB | cluster0-shard-00-02.dga1f.mongodb.net:27017 req:7962 conn:1:4 sconn:572618 | otto.find | STARTED | {"find"=>"users", "filter"=>{"_id"=>BSON::ObjectId('60ccd2aa1d1eab000460ceee')}, "sort"=>{"_id"=>1}, "limit"=>1, "$db"=>"o
tto", "$clusterTime"=>{"clusterTime"=>#<BSON::Timestamp:0x00007fb21c0919d0 @seconds=1626381582, @increment=5>, "signature"=>{"has...
MONGODB | cluster0-shard-00-02.dga1f.mongodb.net:27017 req:7962 | otto.find | SUCCEEDED | 0.147s
Completed 401 Unauthorized in 152ms (MongoDB: 0.1ms | Allocations: 2240)
```

The application utilizes Rails 6.1.3.2, Devise 4.8.0 and Redis 4.3.1.

The API controller that vefiry the login before any method is the following:

```
class ApiController < ActionController::Base
  before_action :check_user,
                except: %i[signin signinEmployee signup signupEmployee forgotPass getFaq getMessages updatePassword contactus
                           getBanners getPartners getCategories getServices getAllServices getServiceDetails getRecommended checkCode getInstructions checkCpf emailCode checkEmail getPipefyUrl log]
  skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token

  def check_user
    if current_user.nil?
      render json: { err: 'Faça seu login antes de continuar' }, status: 401
      nil
    end
  end
end
```

And this is my Devise configurations:

```
Devise.setup do |config|
  config.mailer_sender = 'Equipe Otto <contato@chameotto.com.br>'
  require 'devise/orm/mongoid'
  config.case_insensitive_keys = [:email]
  config.strip_whitespace_keys = [:email]
  config.skip_session_storage = [:http_auth]
  config.stretches = Rails.env.test? ? 1 : 11
  config.reconfirmable = true
  config.expire_all_remember_me_on_sign_out = true
  config.password_length = 6..128
  config.email_regexp = /\A[^@\s]+@[^@\s]+\z/
  config.timeout_in = 25.minutes
  config.reset_password_within = 6.hours
  config.sign_out_via = :delete
end
```

I have also configured a session_store.rb with:

```
Rails.application.config.session_store :cookie_store, expire_after: 10.years
```

The ideia behind it was to avoid the mobile app session from expiring, but I don't know if it is the correct aproach to the problem.

And last of all, this is my application.rb:

```
require_relative 'boot'

require 'rails'
require 'active_model/railtie'
require 'active_job/railtie'
require 'action_controller/railtie'
require 'action_mailer/railtie'
require 'action_view/railtie'
require 'action_cable/engine'
require 'sprockets/railtie'

DEVISE_ORM = :mongoid

Bundler.require(*Rails.groups)

Dotenv::Railtie.load if Rails.env.development?

module Otto
  class Application < Rails::Application
    config.load_defaults 6.1

    config.to_prepare do
      Devise::SessionsController.layout 'login'
      Devise::RegistrationsController.layout proc { |_controller| usuario_signed_in? ? 'application' : 'login' }
      Devise::ConfirmationsController.layout 'login'
      Devise::UnlocksController.layout 'login'
      Devise::PasswordsController.layout 'login'
    end
    config.paths.add Rails.root.join('lib').to_s, eager_load: true
    config.i18n.default_locale = 'pt-BR'
    config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false
    config.encoding = 'utf-8'
    config.time_zone = 'Brasilia'
    config.middleware.use Rack::Attack
    
    config.active_job.queue_adapter = :sidekiq

    require "i18n/backend/fallbacks"
    I18n::Backend::Simple.send(:include, I18n::Backend::Fallbacks)
    config.i18n.fallbacks = {'pt-BR' => 'en'}
  end
end
```

I also have this skeleton of my EmployeesController, I'm showing only the methods names to avoid excess of code:

```
class Api::EmployeesController < ApiController
  before_action :defineNextService,
                except: %i[rate acceptOrder rejectOrder addFavorite removeFavorite addNoWork removeNoWork]

  def addFavorite
    ##code##
  end

  def getAgenda
    ##code##
  end

  def removeFavorite
    ##code##
  end

  def addNoWork
    ##code##
  end

  def removeNoWork
    ##code##
  end

  def getHistory
    ##code##
  end

  def getMoney
    ##code##
  end

  def rate
    ##code##
  end

  def nextService
    ##code##
  end

  def acceptOrder
    ##code##
  end

  def rejectOrder
    ##code##
  end

  def defineNextService
    ##code##
end
```

Comment: you should show your controller code

Comment: I don't know exactly what controller I should show, because it happens in all of them

Comment: i think SessionController / ApplicationController ... you should provide more information

Comment: How do you authenticate against the server? Is it possible that you have to rotate or renew the token after sometime? This would usually be required when you us OAuth.

Comment: @LamPhan I tried to add anything I thought could help

Comment: @spickermann I'm new to the project, but I'm almost sure we don't use OAuth in it, as far as I know we only use the Devise authetication

Comment: any `prepend_before_action` on `Api::EmployeesController` ? could you also show `Api::EmployeesController` code ?

Comment: Sorry for the time it took for me to answer, but I've put the skeleton of the EmployeesController code in the question @LamPhan

Comment: base on code you've provided so far, i still not figure out the cause lead to `exceedMax loop redirect`. you should set break point at the method `check_user` to make sure that the process jump into it because your server log seems to me that it's not, if it jump to that method and response 401, the log should contains `Filter chain halted as :check_user`. i think you need to check 3rd gem or middlewares instead.